# После инициализации bower не устанавливается

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, jquery-ui, bower

**После инициализации bower не устанавливается в терминале Visual Studio Code.**

```
PS C:\Users\Lev80\Desktop\les6_jQuery-ui\hw> bower init
bower existing      The existing bower.json file will be used and filled in
? name hw
? description
? main file
? keywords
? authors
? license MIT
? homepage
? set currently installed components as dependencies? No
? add commonly ignored files to ignore list? No
? would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from being accidentally published to the registry? Yes

{
  name: 'hw',
  description: '',
  main: '',
  license: 'MIT',
  homepage: '',
  private: true
}

? Looks good? Yes
```

**После команды** `**bower install jquery-ui --save**`
**выдает ошибку**

```
bower                           ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH
```

Comment: git установлен, но ошибка с bower все еще есть..

Answer (score 1):

Решение этой ошибки кроется в том что перед этим не был установлен глобальный bower. Вот команда:

```
npm install -g bower
```